# React-native fbsdknext when first logIn on android Profile.getCurrentProfile return null

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Faced a problem while using react-native-fbsdk-next.

The first call to Profile.getCurrentProfile on android returns null. Everything works correctly on ios. If authorization is then called again, the user profile is returned correctly.

If you log out and then try to log in, the first attempt will return null.

Please tell me how to fix this?

```
const platformPermissions =
      Platform.OS === 'ios'
        ? [['public_profile', 'email'], 'limited', 'my_nonce']
        : [['public_profile', 'email']];

    const accessToken = yield LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(
      ...platformPermissions,
    ).then(
      async response => {
        if (response.isCancelled) {
          return;
        }

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          const result = await AuthenticationToken.getAuthenticationTokenIOS();

          return result?.authenticationToken;
        }

        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          const result = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

          return result?.accessToken;
        }
      },
      error => {},
    );

    if (accessToken) {
      const currentProfile = yield Profile.getCurrentProfile(
        profile => profile,
      );

      if (currentProfile) {
        const userData =
          Platform.OS === 'ios'
            ? {
                ...currentProfile,
                firstName: currentProfile.name.split(' ')[0] || null,
                lastName: currentProfile.name.split(' ')[1] || null,
              }
            : currentProfile;

        const {data} = yield Axios.post(ROUTES.AUTH.FACEBOOK_SIGN, {
          ...userData,
          accessToken,
        });

        yield put(setCurrentUser({user: data}));
        yield put(setMethod({method: 'facebook'}));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the library itself. PR needs to be created for the solution. Checkout the progress at https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/73

Comment: So why is this in production ? is there a previous working version or a workaround?

Comment: @acmoune Doesn't seem that there was working version previously. Workaround would be to add a simple if statement that proceeds only if the returned data aren't null.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue with the LoginButton. I have no issue when using LoginManager with a custom Button.

My Custom Login button:

```
const FBLoginButton = () => {
  const nav = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Login with Facebook"
      onPress={() => {
        LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile"]).then(
          function (result) {
            if (result.isCancelled) {
              console.log("Login cancelled");
            } else {
              console.log("Success");
              nav.navigate("Home"); // Go to Home screen
            }
          },
          function (error) {
            console.log("Login fail with error: " + error);
          }
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

My Home Screen

```
import { Profile } from "react-native-fbsdk-next";
    
const HomeScreen = () => {
      const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    
      const nav = useNavigation();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        Profile.getCurrentProfile().then((profile) => {
          if (profile) {
            setCurrentUser(profile);
          }
        });
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <View>
          {currentUser ? (
            <>
              <Text>{`id: ${currentUser.userID}, name: ${currentUser.name}`}</Text>
              <Button
                title="Logout"
                onPress={() => {
                  LoginManager.logOut();
                  nav.navigate("Login");
                }}
              />
            </>
          ) : (
            <Text>Loading...</Text>
          )}
        </View>
      );
    };
```